# I can't control Ubuntu from my android device

Tags: networking, android, remote, ip

I get some applications on android for control remotely my computer, but it just dont work

The applications need the ip direction. I provide it. (I tried with different ones. Diffusion direction, subnet mask, DNS,etc) 
But the application can't connect.

Is there some permission in Ubiuntu to have to provide before try to connect? 
Thanks

Comment: It is usually about firewall configuration but can you please say which apps have you used in order to reproduce your scenery and provide you some help on this? Thank you!

Comment: Which app are trying on Android?

Comment: Home Remote Control , Virtual Tablet, Wifi Drawing, Remote link. Some times Home Remote says: _connection is closed by foreing host_ or _Auth fail_. Thank you.